# Refresh one row in Dataset from Database before show edit form

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, refresh, row

I have a DataSet + TableAdapter and bound dataGridView. I have an edit button which opens a new form with details to edit (WinForms). How do I refresh one row (selected one) in the Dataset and in dataGrid from database before opening the new form?

Example: Two users A and B. User A changed record ID(10) and user B still has the old value in record ID(10). User B presses edit button and should get fresh data from database (data after change made by user A).

```
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        da.Fill(ds, "Orders");
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        .....
           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
           //?
           //refresh selected row in datagrid (from current database record)
           //?
           EditForm()
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new query in your TableAdapter that should only get one row and call it with just the primary key of the row you already have.

Plug the result into a new DataSet and grab the first row (after checking for Rows.Count() > 0)

Comment: Ok, but how replace old one record from old dataset by the new one. And how refresh only one record in datagridview.

Comment: That's not possible, and you don't need to do it. When your edit form loads, get the latest version of that single record and use it to populate the fields on the edit box. Then when it's saved, and the edit form is closed, you'll want to refresh the whole dataset. This is because if you're worried about a single row being updated, then you should probably update the whole thing anyway. Well, it is possible, but you'd have to do a lot of work to manually edit the local record, and make sure that it doesn't trigger a save of that row again, compounding concurrency issues. IMO, not worth it.

Comment: I do that in similar way but in same cases I'd like to refresh only one row. You have probably right not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I would enclose the populating the gridview bit in it's own method say something like fill_grid(). Then just call the method in the edit link click event. Then whatever has changed will update. Then add the method to all the other button link events too. Then every time the user is clicking a link the grid "refreshes" essentially.

Answer (score 0):

For those who is looking for the answer in 2019,
assuming `dataAdapter` is a defined earlier class member

```
    private void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGrid.SelectedItem is DataRowView view)
        {
            DataRow currentRow = view.Row;
            DataTable table = currentRow.Table;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table.Rows.IndexOf(currentRow), 1, table);
        }
    }
```